# How do i merge two or more project file into one project for a java based web app?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

i got a web project.i used gof[struts,hibernate,spring,.,.]pattern. actually i not good in struts so my friend taking care of the struts part.well, the problem is ,***

> how to merge our project and 
>   we both want to see our code every time whatever the change happen

*** .bec we are beginners

Answer (score 2):

You may want to actually keep your project split in modules and use a Code Versioning System(CVS). At the moment, most popular/used are Git and SVN. If you don't have a server, you can use BitBucket to host your code in private or GitHub/Google Code if you want to open source it.

Answer (score 0):

Use SVN or CSV if you have server. other wise you can use online Repository like GitHub.